# How can we implement put operation using dropwizard

Tags: java, dropwizard

I tried to look online for examples that use the put rest method that is similar to the dropwizard example on github, but I haven't really found any.

here is my PersonDAO.java code

```
public class PersonDAO extends AbstractDAO<Person> {
    public PersonDAO(SessionFactory factory) {
        super(factory);
    }
    public Optional<Person> findById(Long id) {
        return Optional.fromNullable(get(id));
    }

    public Person create(Person person) {
        return persist(person);
    }

    public List<Person> findAll() {
        return list(namedQuery("com.example.helloworld.core.Person.findAll"));
    }
    //here i want to create delete method
}
```

here is my rest api code:

```
@Path("/people")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class PeopleResource {

    private final PersonDAO peopleDAO;

    public PeopleResource(PersonDAO peopleDAO) {
        this.peopleDAO = peopleDAO;
    }

    @POST
    @UnitOfWork
    public Person createPerson(Person person) {
        return peopleDAO.create(person);
    }

    @GET
    @UnitOfWork
    public List<Person> listPeople() {
        return peopleDAO.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Optional<Person> getUser(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        Optional<Person> person = peopleDAO.findPeopleById(id);
        return person;
    }
    //here should be put method that calls dao class
}
```

here is my person.java class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
@NamedQueries(
    {
        @NamedQuery(
            name = "com.example.helloworld.core.Person.findAll",
            query = "SELECT p FROM Person p"
        )
    }
)
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "fullName", nullable = false)
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name = "jobTitle", nullable = false)
    private String jobTitle;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String fullName, String jobTitle) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Person)) {
            return false;
        }

        final Person that = (Person) o;

        return Objects.equals(this.id, that.id) &&
                Objects.equals(this.fullName, that.fullName) &&
                Objects.equals(this.jobTitle, that.jobTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, fullName, jobTitle);
    }
}
```

Is there any easy ways/suggestions to implement the put method?

Comment: Do you mean a put request? You can use the @ Get, @ Post, @ Put, @ Delete annotations above the resource method to specify which operations it supports. Is there an error you're getting when you try?

Answer (score 0):

resource:

```
@PUT
public Person update(Person person) {
    return peopleDAO.update(person);
}
```

dao:

```
public Person update(Person person) {
    return persist(person);
}
```

be sure your id is not null. persist logic create or update.

Comment: Will this replace an entry in the database? For Example if I use put request and my url in localhost http://localhost:8080/people/2, where two is the primary id of the database, will that update the second entry in the database?

Comment: yes. if you dont have any control. For like this states, i using a column with @Version annotation.
For example

Comment: @Version
    private long lastUpdated;